# How to change TimeZone based on user TimeZone

Tags: java, jsf, timezone, seam

I would like to use different `TimeZone` base on the User's `TimeZone`.

**Question :** Is there any feature to set default in `JSF` or `Seam`?
It will be effect the whole application.

I hope, the feature will be effect `s:convertDateTime`, `f:convertDateTime`, `p:calendar`, etc...  every time I use without using `timezone` attribute.

I also tried to use `Seam` component `TimeZoneSelector` as below.

```
@In
private TimeZoneSelector timeZoneSelector;
....
timeZoneSelector.setTimeZone(user.getTimeZone());
```

But, it does not effect on `<f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:mm a"/>` automatically.
I have to retrieve `TimeZone` form backing bean again.

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:mm a" timeZone="#{mybean.timeZone}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSF does not have default special feature allows you this. You need to take the implementation of this functional.

Comment: Thz, for your answer. Is there any way in `Seam`?

Comment: Perhaps this [paragraph](http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/JSFEnhancementDefaultApplicationTimeZone) from the documentation will help you.

Comment: I already get this. I think, it is not answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

1- create a default converter for `java.util.Date`

2- in the the `getAsString` and `getAsObject` have the converter retrieve the user timezone from the session

3- use `SimpleDateFormat.setTimezone()` before parsing/formatting